# PHP: file_get_contents only working once

Tags: php, json, post

Using PHP 5.3.3, I am unable to access input JSON from `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));` more than once.  I have verified the output of the following test:

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonInput = json_decode($json);
```

I get this result:

```
string(394) "{"siteID":"104"}"
string(0) ""
```

I have even tried setting a `global` value from the first `file_get_contents`, but that value still turns up as `NULL`.

I have noted this strange behaviour only occurs when the `UPDATE` header is present (`POST` appears to work fine with my current PHP installation).

How can I fix my current PHP 5.3.3 installation so that I can access the contents of `file_get_contents('php://input')` several times?

Comment: In documentation `Note: Prior to PHP 5.6, a stream opened with php://input could only be read once; the stream did not support seek operations. However, depending on the SAPI implementation, it may be possible to open another php://input stream and restart reading. This is only possible if the request body data has been saved. Typically, this is the case for POST requests, but not other request methods, such as PUT or PROPFIND.`

Comment: I don't read any solutions in the link provided.  How can I access the file input stream **more than once**?

Comment: Solution? Update to php 5.6. Or store the data from the first opening. This is a limitation within the language.